# Sed : select lines between two timestamps

Tags: bash, sed

I want to select lines between two timestamps - 60 minutes before and now

My command is

```
sed -n '/"$(date -d '60 minutes ago'  +"%H:%m")"/,/"$(date -d  +"%H:%m")"/p'  /var/www/html/glpi/files/_log/event.log/
```

But i get :

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unterminated address regex
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In single quotes, `$(` and `"` are not treated specially, and single quotes don't nest.

You also probably don't want to use the `%H:%m` format, as it means `hour:month`.

```
sed -n "/$(date -d 60\ minutes\ ago +%H:%M)/,\$p"
```

But if the exact time wasn't logged, it wouldn't work. It might be better to use a more powerful language than `sed` that can actually parse the timestamps and compare them properly.